# Need Reg Exp. to match fixed length field for digits and spaces only

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to get a reg. Expression to match a pattern of exactly 11 digits OR 0 to 10 digits padded to 11 characters w/ spaces (\x20).

```
Match: “12345678901”,  “           “, “123        “

Don't Match: “    5678901”, “123   78901”, “123   789  ”
```

The expression `'/((\d)|(\x20)){11}/'`  matches the desired strings however it also still matches strings that have leading and internal spaces.  I've played w/ various combinations of the leading / trailing anchors (^,$) but can't seem to get the right result.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Are you trying to match or validate?

Comment: I'm trying to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=\d* *$)[\d ]{11}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV6lM2/2)

Comment: You can test for `(?=\d* *$)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh: yes that will be simpler

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh very sweet. never having use look-ahead I'd love to hear a brief explanation of the expression if you would indulge.

Comment: `(?=\d* *$)` is a lookahead that means allow this match only if pattern is 0 or more digits followed by 0 or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to test this condition in your code, cause regex will be too ugly.

```
\d{11}|\s\d{10}|\s{2}\d{9}|\s{3}\d{8}|\s{4}\d{7}|\s{5}\d{6}|\s{6}\d{5}|\s{7}\d{4}|\s{8}\d{3}|\s{9}\d{2}|\s{10}\d|\s{11}
```

Comment: @Mike: The code is extremely hard to maintain like this. Consider using the other solution.

Comment: Yes, this code is too hard to understand and to maintain.