# Java Regular Expression Combined Length

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a number with padding spaces. The total length is four.
For example:

```
(   1)
(  43)
( 232)
(1239)
```

What I'm currently doing is list all the four cases and combined them with "`|`". There should be a better way to do it.

Maybe `{min, max}` could do the job?
Can anyone give some help?

Edit:
With the help of you guys, I get it now. It's `^(?= *\d*$)[\d ]{4}$`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would write a pattern for "any amount of whitespaces, then some numbers, then again some whitespaces" and write the length constraint of 4 in plain java.

Comment: Hint: consider adding your current regex to the question. Might help us to improve it. Sigh.

Comment: Have a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824742/2055998

Comment: It's a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27824494/2988730

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Reg Exp. to match fixed length field for digits and spaces only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824494/need-reg-exp-to-match-fixed-length-field-for-digits-and-spaces-only)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use this regex, you can use Patterns for example :

```
String str = "(  123)";
int paddingLength = 5;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\s*)(\\d*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find() && m.group(1).length() + m.group(2).length() == paddingLength) {
    System.out.println("Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Match");
}
```

Or like @Mad Physicist mention in comment you can use :

```
if (m.find() && m.group(0).length() - 2 == paddingLength) {
```

---

If your string match the regex, and the length of the first group plus the length of the second group equal to the real length then print match, else not match

Comment: why this down-vote?

Comment: This does not preserve the total length in any way shape or form.

Comment: this is correct @MadPhysicist can you check now please

Comment: Nope. That matches `(  ??)`. You can't use a quantifier like that in a character class. @PM77-1 already linked to the correct solution.

Comment: what about this solution @MadPhysicist

Comment: That's not a strictly regex solution. Not only does it rely on a whole lot of post-processing, but you have the "Not Match" handler repeated in two places.

Comment: yes @MadPhysicist because maybe if your string is not match the regex you get Not match, if match you still need to check the length for that i used two

Comment: At least use the `and` operator to have a single `else` block...

Comment: yes @MadPhysicist this is correct thank you, i already change it

Comment: Also, as an FYI, `m.group(1).length() + m.group(2).length() == m.group(0).length() - 2`. Group #0 is the entire match.

Comment: I still think this is an extremely cumbersome solution for something that can be solved with a short regex which OP has even edited into the question.

Comment: what did you mean **Also, as an FYI, m.group(1).length() + m.group(2).length() == m.group(0).length() - 2. Group #0 is the entire match** i don't get you, and can you please show me the regex that match this case, i can't arrive to find it @MadPhysicist

Comment: I just meant that your `if` could read `if (m.find() && m.group(0).length() - 2 == paddingLength)`. Shorter, but arguably less clear than what you have.

Comment: thank you, i already edit my answer, can you please remove this not correct down-vote, my answer is correct, so why this down-vote @MadPhysicist and until now, you don't provide to me the regex that match this case :)

Comment: I have removed my downvote, but I will not flip it. I still think your answer is over-engineered and unnecessarily clunky, but that's just my opinion. Someone else may find it useful.

Comment: ok, thank you @MadPhysicist can you please provide to me how this `^(?=\d* *$)[\d ]{11}$` solve the problem?

Comment: Read the post it came from for details, but it basically checks that you have something of the form numbers followed by padding (needs to be reversed for this post) using a lookahead, then checks that there is the correct number of characters of the correct type.

Comment: can you simplify it and gives me the regex please @MadPhysicist ?

Comment: OP literally has it in their post. I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: oh i don't see it thank you @MadPhysicist i know you hate me today because i asked a lot i'm sorry

Comment: I don't hate you. Figuring stuff out is hard and I appreciate you taking the effort to learn a new thing.